# GAE: hiding sensitive website files / information

Tags: java, google-app-engine

My website on GAE (Java 8 Environment) is working fine. However, I found out that files that are not in the WEB-INF folder, is accessible by the public simply by opening it in the browser e.g. https://example.net/resources/file.txt.

Several files, including javascript files, contain sensitive and security information that I wish to make inaccessible to the public. How do I this?

I had issues putting them in the WEB-INF folder since I couldn't figure out the proper way to reference them for the website to use e.g. < script >relative path to web-inf folder + resource< /script >.

If I could be taught to use WEB-INF properly, I would accept that as an answer to this question as well.

Edit:
There's some need for clarification. What I need to protect are the resource files. I understand that scripts need to be publicly accessible, in order for them to execute on the client side, though it would be great if I could somehow put them in the WEB-INF folder while still having them accessible for the site's execution.

But ultimately, if there was a method to fetch info from resources in the WEB-INF folder, via Javascript (or whatever can do the job outside a Servlet), then this will solve my issue. The resources are simply files containing text like keys, certain email addresses etc.

Comment: Would you not be able to simply just write (if you have an Apache server) an `.htaccess` file which makes that directory forbidden?

Comment: thanks for the comment. from what I've read GAE does not support .htaccess files and what I require cannot be done via the app.yaml file.

Comment: Which files your app serves and how is entirely under the control of your app - a combination of your app config files and the matching logic in your app handlers. But you'd need to provide them to get a more specific answer.

Comment: thank you Dan. Technically it only (should) serves the website. I have no other files (e.g. downloadables) that I want to share with visitors. Everything is under control of the app (if I understood your question correctly). I did some reading into the sensitive info I mentioned (e.g. firebase and stripe api keys) and found that it might be ok for people to find out about them, since they can't be used to do anything on the server-side. Still, if I could hide my script files from being pulled up on a public browser, I'd feel a lot better.

Comment: But this doesn't make sense, if the scripts  you are referring to are javascript  you can't prevent someone viewing them if they are to be loaded by the browser.  Any reference to a URL path in a <script> tag can be copied and tried without any way for you to protect them.

Comment: This is what I know as well, but the WEB-INF folder in GAE prevents public access to its contents while being accessible to application. I want to know if there was a way to leverage this (or some other sort of) protection.

Thinking about it some more, I might just pull the sensitive info from a data source somewhere, though I'd like that solution less.

Comment: Edited my post to clarify things further. Sorry, lack of sleep...

Comment: What I mean is: for a file to be served it has to either be in a static_dir, or match a static_file pattern, or simply be served by one of your handlers. Just find how exactly is your file served and prevent that.

Comment: I've come upon the security-constraint tag for the deployment file, and it can limit or prevent access, but it's all or nothing. 

If I place an admin/role restriction, for example, on the resources folder, it becomes unreachable via a browser but also becomes unusable to the page :(

I guess this means that I have to accept things being as they are.